# Automatically create One-To-One relation when using reverse field

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, relational-database, one-to-one

When creating two instances of a model and connecting them using a OneToOneField, the connection gets created and saved automatically at object creation:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    next = models.OneToOneField('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='prev', null=True, blank=True)

>>> m2 = MyModel.objects.create(name="2")
>>> m1 = MyModel.objects.create(name="1", next=m2)
>>> m2.prev
<MyModel: 1>
>>> m2.refresh_from_db()
>>> m2.prev
<MyModel: 2>
```

However, when creating the same connection but using the reverse field, the creation is also done automatically but **not** the save.

```
>>> m1 = MyModel.objects.create(name="1")
>>> m2 = MyModel.objects.create(name="2", prev=m1)
>>> m1.next
<MyModel: 2>
>>> m1.refresh_from_db()
>>> m1.next
```

*Note that the last statement doesn't print anything since it returns `None`*

---

How can I have it always save the relation when created using the reverse field without having to manually use `.save()` each time?

Comment: Why does it change the `prev` value when you call refresh_from_db? Is that the expected result?

Comment: `prev` isn't in the database when `refresh_from_db` is called and is therefore replaced with what is in the database, i.e. `None`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably simple way to achieve this could be using pre_save/post_save signal which you see as a viable solution. But not sure how viable this answer would be, try to make some mods and see if this works!

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    next = models.OneToOneField('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='prev', null=True, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def mymodel_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     if hasattr(instance, 'prev'): # if prev exists
          # now check if prev is added next
          if not instance.prev.next: # if next is not present 
                 instance.prev.next = instance
                 MyModel.objects.filter(
                     pk=instance.prev.pk
                 ).update(next=instance)
```

Comment: `if not instance.prev.next` will always evaluate to false since it doesn't check what is actually in the database, only in memory. Removing the check would mean that the update will always be called. Would need something that checks what has only been changed in memory.

Answer (score 3):

This is a terrible idea.

You will confuse everyone looking at your code.

I'm even surprised that `MyModel.objects.create` works instead of throwing an invalid keyword argument. I'll probably open a ticked for this.

When you call:

```
m2 = MyModel.objects.create(name="2", prev=m1)
```

in order to work as you expect, the `.create` method needs to call save on the `m1` instance, because `m1` is the instance that holds the relation (via `next`)

Who would expect that? You are hiding functionality. Some quotes from `PEP 20`

> Explicit is better than implicit.
>
> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

My advice is to change the relation to:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    prev = models.OneToOneField('self',
                                null=True,
                                blank=True,
                                related_name='next',
                                on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Because, its much more likely to know what `prev` is at a creation time.